# Why can't I check membership of characters in Strings?

Tags: java, regex, string, exception

I was solving a problem on spoj which gives an expression and I've to evaluate that expression. Like "7+5" is the expression given and I've to evaluate and print 12.

Here is my code

```
public class EXPR2 {
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int t = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    while (t-- > 0) {
      String expression = input.readLine();
      String[] components = new String[3];
      int ans = 0;
      if (expression.contains("+")) {
        components = expression.split("+");
        ans = Integer.parseInt(components[0]) + Integer.parseInt(components[1]);

      } else if (expression.contains("-")) {
        components = expression.split("-");
        ans = Integer.parseInt(components[0]) + Integer.parseInt(components[1]);

      } else if (expression.contains("*")) {
        components = expression.split("*");
        ans = Integer.parseInt(components[0]) * Integer.parseInt(components[1]);
      } else {
        components = expression.split("/");
        ans = Integer.parseInt(components[0]) / Integer.parseInt(components[1]);

      }
      System.out.println(ans);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am getting exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2368)
    at java.lang.String.split(String.java:2410)
    at EXPR2.main(EXPR2.java:15)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: on various different inputs it gives different line numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression, so you must escape `+` with `\\`.

For example:

```
String foo = "7+5";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(foo.split("\\+")));
```

Output:

```
[7, 5]
```

In your case this would be:

```
components = expression.split("\\+");
```

Answer (score 2):

The spit method of String has regex as an argument, so you need to escape any regex meaningful characters (+,*).